# Overwrite some partitions of a partitioned table Bigquery

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am currently trying to develop a Dataflow pipeline in order to replace some partitions of a partitioned table. I have a custom partition field which is a date. The input of my pipeline is a file with potentially different dates.

I developed a Pipeline :

```
    PipelineOptionsFactory.register(BigQueryOptions.class);
    BigQueryOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().as(BigQueryOptions.class);

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);

    PCollection<TableRow> rows =  p.apply("ReadLines", TextIO.read().from(options.getFileLocation()))
            .apply("Convert To BQ Row", ParDo.of(new StringToRowConverter(options)));



    ValueProvider<String>  projectId = options.getProjectId();
    ValueProvider<String> datasetId = options.getDatasetId();
    ValueProvider<String> tableId = options.getTableId();
    ValueProvider<String> partitionField = options.getPartitionField();
    ValueProvider<String> columnNames = options.getColumnNames();
    ValueProvider<String> types = options.getTypes();

    rows.apply("Write to BQ", BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
            .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
            .withCustomGcsTempLocation(options.getGCSTempLocation())
            .to(new DynamicDestinations<TableRow, String>() {

                @Override
                public String getDestination(ValueInSingleWindow<TableRow> element) {

                    TableRow date = element.getValue();

                    String partitionDestination = (String) date.get(partitionField.get());

                    SimpleDateFormat from = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    SimpleDateFormat to = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

                    try {

                        partitionDestination = to.format(from.parse(partitionDestination));
                        LOG.info("Table destination "+partitionDestination);
                        return projectId.get()+":"+datasetId.get()+"."+tableId.get()+"$"+partitionDestination;

                    } catch(ParseException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return projectId.get()+":"+datasetId.get()+"."+tableId.get()+"_rowsWithErrors";
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public TableDestination getTable(String destination) {

                    TimePartitioning timePartitioning = new TimePartitioning();
                    timePartitioning.setField(partitionField.get());
                    timePartitioning.setType("DAY");
                    timePartitioning.setRequirePartitionFilter(true);

                    TableDestination tableDestination  = new TableDestination(destination, null, timePartitioning);

                    LOG.info(tableDestination.toString());

                    return tableDestination;

                }

                @Override
                public TableSchema getSchema(String destination) {

                        return new TableSchema().setFields(buildTableSchemaFromOptions(columnNames, types));
                }
            })
            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
    );

    p.run();
}
```

When I trigger the pipeline locally, it successfully replacesthe partitions which date are in the input file. Nevertheless, when deploying on Google Cloud Dataflow and running the template with the exact same parameters, it truncates all the data, and I just have at the end the file I wanted to upload in my table.

Do you know why there is such a difference ?

Thank you !

Comment: There should be no difference between running locally and in the cloud. Are you sure what you've described is actually happening?

Comment: Hello Graham, thank you for your answer, yes I am sure : I generated a template from my beam code, and when I run it with the exact same parameters it overwrites all my partitions.

Comment: @GrahamPolley, I have also tried to launch the pipeline with the Dataflow runner (instead of generating a template), and it still overwrites all the partitions

Comment: Is it possible because you are using `.withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)` instead of `.withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND`

Comment: If that is not the case, could you explain the problem again, because I feel like I am misunderstanding something

Comment: Hello @HarisNadeem, the use case is this one : I have a partitioned table, let's say I have at t 3 partitions for the following dates : 2018-05-01, 2018-05-02, 2018-05-03. At t+1, I have an input file containing data for the 2018-05-02, 2018-05-03. What I want to do is to replace the current partitions for these dates, and leave unchanged the one of  2018-05-01. When I execute the pipeline I developed with the direct runner, everything works fine. But, when I trigger it with the DataflowRunner, it overwrites all the partitions, and I just have in my output 2 partitions.

Comment: Interesting. I have not seen this happen before. Could you try experimenting around with `BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND` and `BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER` in order to see if they make a difference? I'll try to look more into the code and see if I can see the issue.

Comment: @HarisNadeem, the fact is that it is important for me to avoid to have duplicate data, that's why I have made the choice to truncate existing partitions. Thank you for your time !

Comment: @JohnDavid when you are running the dataflow job as a template, are you sending the same data to `partitionField ` as you were in command line? Because from what I can tell, the only difference in the two runs from local and cloud is the `ValueProvider<String>`. So either you are passing different parameters in both runs accidentally, or there is something that ValueProvider is doing underneath that we are not seeing. Maybe you are adding more values to it later in the code?

Comment: @JohnDavid did this ever get answered? I have the same question about replacing only certain partitions with WRITE_TRUNCATE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition to CREATE_IF_NEEDED, and this is paired with BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE, so even if the table exists, it may be recreated. This is the reason why you see your table getting replaced.

See this document [1] for details.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition#CREATE_IF_NEEDED